# border-color with multiple colors

Tags: css, colors, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I found some information about `border-color` and it turns out, that you can specify each of the borders with different colors. My question here is following: Is it possible to specify the left border with two or more colors?
The deal is, that I have a navigation bar, with `li` elements, which are divided with `padding` and a `border` properties. For example:

```
li {
    float: left;
    padding-left&right: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
}
```

and the border is as tall as the text itself in the `li` element. What I need is to get the border shorter than text. So I thought I could give it 3 colors: transparent - white - transparent.

Maybe there is a realistic way to do this? This was just at the top of my head and I found information, that it is not possible to shorten the border under the height of the `li` element.

Comment: If you want a border shorter than the text, you can use a psuedo `:before` or `:after` element.

Answer (score 3):

The most appropriate way to implement this would be to make use of the `border-image` property along with a linear gradient like mentioned in Stephen Brickner's answer. But the downside to it is the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) which is very low at present.

There are a couple of other approaches with better browser support than can be made use of and they are as follows:

#### Method 1: Pseudo Elements with Border

You could make use of a pseudo-element (`:before` or `:after`) with height shorter than the parent `li` element, add a `border` to it and position it appropriately to achieve the required effect. Thickness of the separator line is determined by the width of the pseudo-element's border.

```css
.right-to-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.right-to-left:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  border-right: 2px solid;
}

/* just for demo */

body {
  background: black;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-to-left">Some text <br/> and more</div>
<div class="right-to-left">Some text <br/> and more</div>
<div class="right-to-left">Some text <br/> and more</div>
```

This method has the [highest browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) among the possible options. However, it cannot be used if more than one color is required for the separator (or) a gradient effect is required.

---

#### Method 2: Background Gradients

You could add a `linear-gradient` as background image to the element and position it appropriately to produce a line shorter than the text. In this approach, thickness of the separator line is determined by the width of the background image.

```css
.right-to-left {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 25%, white 25%, white 75%, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 2px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
}
.right-to-left.multi {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 25%, red 25%, white 75%, transparent 75%);
}

/* just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  color: white;
}
hr{ clear: both; }
div{ margin: 10px 0px; }
```

```html
<!-- prefix free library to support old browsers and avoid prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="right-to-left">Some text <br/> and more</div>
<div class="right-to-left">Some text <br/> and more</div>
<div class="right-to-left">Some text <br/> and more</div>

<hr>

<div class="right-to-left multi">Some text <br/> and more</div>
<div class="right-to-left multi">Some text <br/> and more</div>
<div class="right-to-left multi">Some text <br/> and more</div>
```

The [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) for this is better than `border-image` approach but worse when compared with the pseudo-element approach. The advantage is that the separator can have multiple colors or even a gradient pattern like in the above snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a transform on it. Example:

```
.right-to-left {
    border-width: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    -moz-border-image:
      -moz-linear-gradient(left, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%; 
    -o-border-image:
      -o-linear-gradient(left, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    border-image:
      linear-gradient(to left, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;     
}
```